# how to start a new report on a new page in php

Tags: php, html, mysql, css

Hi i have a form which consist three part, namely the letter part, the detail part and the notes part
i am able to print the letter report but now i want to start the new report on a new page i mean when a user tries to print the report the letter part should come on a page and the detail part on a newpage which will be A4 for all pages can anybody help me in this?
i just want to know how to use while with tables
for eg.

```
<?php
echo "table";
while($row= mysql_fetch_array($result)){
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>$row[data1]</td>";
echo "<td>$row[data2]</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `page-break-before: always` CSS in your table start tag, i.e.

```
echo '<table style="page-break-before: always">';
```

*Sidenote:* MDN suggests that it should be replaced by `break-before` ( see reference link ), but I DO NOT suggest it, as there is nearly no browser supporting this new CSS3 property.

p.s. I believe the first line should be `echo "<table>";` , right?

Reference : [page-break-brefore on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/page-break-before)

Example:

```
<?php
echo '<table style="page-break-before: always">';
while($row= mysql_fetch_array($result)){ // Do NOT use mysql_* functions! Use MySQLi / PDO instead
  echo '<tr style="margin-top: 20px;">';
  echo "  <td>$row[data1]</td>";
  echo "  <td>$row[data2]</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
?>
```

Comment: so if i add a page break so will the next report will start on a new page

Comment: Yes. Correct. This will start a new page.

Comment: its working fine but i want to leave some space from top wen a new page is started so is it possible along with page-break

Comment: Yes. You can add `margin-top` or `padding-top` in your `<tr>` ( depends on how you use the CSS )

Comment: do you know how to use CSS ? added example.

Answer (score 0):

this mightbe helpful :

***CSS Page Breaks***

```
@media all {
    .page-break { display: none; }
}

@media print {
    .page-break { display: block; page-break-before: always; }
}
```

***Usage***

```
<h1>Page Title</h1>
<!-- content block -->
<!-- content block -->
<div class="page-break"></div>
<!-- content block -->
<!-- content block -->
<div class="page-break"></div>
<!-- content block -->
<!-- content -->
```

Comment: no need to use `@media` to branch CSS. You can just add it to table tag. plus, `page-break-before` does not have visual effects other than printing.